# Как добавить класс элементу по клику (JQuery)

Tags: css, jquery

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при клике на `button` (троеточие в правом нижнем углу), карточка переворачивалась на 180 град. (**Flip card**). Для этого нужно двум `div` добавить класс анимации. Легко сделал это через `toggleClass`, проблема в том, что класс добавляется ко всем карточкам, а не к той, куда происходит клик. Как решить?

```js
$(".button-card-boat").click(function() {
  $('.front-card-boat').toggleClass('animation-front-card');
  $('.back-card-boat').toggleClass('animation-back-card');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-boat-models">
  <div class="front-card-boat">
    <div class="blockimgFrontCard">
      <img src="image/models-boats/Слой%2011.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <span class="nameModelCardBoat">Baron</span>
    <p>Looking for the perfect big water aluminum fishing boat? The legendary 2275 Lund Baron is our flagship fishing boat model.</p>
    <img class="button-card-boat" src="image/models-boats/menu.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="back-card-boat">
    <span class="nameModelCardBoat">Baron</span>
    <div class="infoModelBoat" style="width: 80%;">
      <div class="p-container">
        <span>1975</span>
        <p>18' 10"</p>
        <p>135-200 л. с.</p>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="p-container">
        <span>1975</span>
        <p>18' 10"</p>
        <p>135-200 л. с.</p>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="p-container">
        <span>1975</span>
        <p>18' 10"</p>
        <p>135-200 л. с.</p>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="p-container">
        <span>1975</span>
        <p>18' 10"</p>
        <p>135-200 л. с.</p>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <img class="button-card-boat" src="image/models-boats/menu.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите `HTML`  строение

Comment: Добавил в топик

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил задачу с помощью чистого JS (делегирование события):

```
document.querySelector('.boats-models').onclick = function (event) {
    if(event.target.className === 'button-card-boat'){
        event.path[2].querySelector('.front-card-boat').classList.toggle('animation-front-card');
        event.path[2].querySelector('.back-card-boat').classList.toggle('animation-back-card');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, контейнер `card-boat-models` это блок одной карточки, если так, то для корректного использования `toggleClass` используйте `this + parent`

> После обсуждения откорректировал ваш пример, вот рабочий вариант, вам
>   просто надо к первому предку обращаться....

```js
$(".button-card-boat").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.front-card-boat').toggleClass('animation-front-card');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.back-card-boat').toggleClass('animation-back-card');
});
```

```css
.boats-models{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
.row-boats-models{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 align-items: center;
 width: 88.9vw;
}
.card-boat-models{
    position: relative;
 width: 21.8vw;
 max-width: 419px;
 min-width: 400px;
 height: 423px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    margin: 15px;
   
}


.front-card-boat, .back-card-boat{
    position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 1s;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 34px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.front-card-boat{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 align-items: center;
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.front-card-boat, .back-card-boat {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;

  } 

.back-card-boat{
 display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.animation-front-card{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.animation-back-card{
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
}


.front-card-boat > p {
 padding: 0 15px 34px;
 color: #191a2d;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 800;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;

}

.nameModelCardBoat {
 padding: 49px 0px 32px;
 color: #800d13;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 22px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.button-card-boat{
 align-self: flex-end;
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.p-container{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
}
.p-container > p{
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 color: #191a2d;
 font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin: 20px 0;
}
.p-container > span{
    color: #800d13;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.infoModelBoat > hr{
width: 88%;
color: #e8e8e8;
background-color: #e8e8e8;
height: 1px;
margin: auto;
border: none;
}
.nameModelCardBoat:before{
    content: '–';
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 28px;
}
.nameModelCardBoat:after{
    content: '–';
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.button-card-boat{
background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boats-models">
   <div class="row-boats-models">
    <div class="card-boat-models">
      <div class="front-card-boat">
                        <div class="blockimgFrontCard">
                        <img src="image/models-boats/Слой%2011.png" alt="">
                        </div>
         <span class="nameModelCardBoat">Baron</span>
         <p>Looking for the perfect big water aluminum fishing boat? The legendary 2275 Lund Baron is our flagship fishing boat model.</p>
         <img class="button-card-boat" src="image/models-boats/menu.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="back-card-boat">
       <span class="nameModelCardBoat">Baron</span>
         <div class="infoModelBoat" style="width: 80%;">
         <div class="p-container">
          <span>1975</span>
          <p>18' 10"</p>
          <p>135-200 л. с.</p>
         </div>
         <hr>
         <div class="p-container">
          <span>1975</span>
          <p>18' 10"</p>
          <p>135-200 л. с.</p>
         </div>
         <hr>
         <div class="p-container">
          <span>1975</span>
          <p>18' 10"</p>
          <p>135-200 л. с.</p>
         </div>
         <hr>
         <div class="p-container">
          <span>1975</span>
          <p>18' 10"</p>
          <p>135-200 л. с.</p>
         </div>
         <hr>
         </div>
         <img class="button-card-boat" src="image/models-boats/menu.png" alt="">
      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-boat-models">
                    <div class="front-card-boat">
                    <div class="blockimgFrontCard">
                    <img src="image/models-boats/Слой%2011.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <span class="nameModelCardBoat">Baron</span>
                    <p>Looking for the perfect big water aluminum fishing boat? The legendary 2275 Lund Baron is our flagship fishing boat model.</p>
                    <img class="button-card-boat" src="image/models-boats/menu.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="back-card-boat">
                        <span class="nameModelCardBoat">Baron</span>
                    <div class="infoModelBoat" style="width: 80%;">
                    <div class="p-container">
                        <span>1975</span>
                        <p>18' 10"</p>
                        <p>135-200 л. с.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="p-container">
                        <span>1975</span>
                        <p>18' 10"</p>
                        <p>135-200 л. с.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="p-container">
                        <span>1975</span>
                        <p>18' 10"</p>
                        <p>135-200 л. с.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="p-container">
                        <span>1975</span>
                        <p>18' 10"</p>
                        <p>135-200 л. с.</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    </div>
                    <img class="button-card-boat" src="image/models-boats/menu.png" alt="">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-boat-models">
                <div class="front-card-boat">
                <div class="blockimgFrontCard">
                <img src="image/models-boats/Слой%2011.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <span class="nameModelCardBoat">Baron</span>
                <p>Looking for the perfect big water aluminum fishing boat? The legendary 2275 Lund Baron is our flagship fishing boat model.</p>
                <img class="button-card-boat" src="image/models-boats/menu.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="back-card-boat">
                    <span class="nameModelCardBoat">Baron</span>
                <div class="infoModelBoat" style="width: 80%;">
                <div class="p-container">
                    <span>1975</span>
                    <p>18' 10"</p>
                    <p>135-200 л. с.</p>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="p-container">
                    <span>1975</span>
                    <p>18' 10"</p>
                    <p>135-200 л. с.</p>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="p-container">
                    <span>1975</span>
                    <p>18' 10"</p>
                    <p>135-200 л. с.</p>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="p-container">
                    <span>1975</span>
                    <p>18' 10"</p>
                    <p>135-200 л. с.</p>
                </div>
                <hr>
                </div>
                <img class="button-card-boat" src="image/models-boats/menu.png" alt="">
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но в данном случае класс добавляется только родителю (front-card-boat) и карточка просто скрывается(

Comment: @mr.smile ну вы же хотите скрыть только ту карточку которую нажали? родитель front-card-boat получает клас animation-front-card а back-card-boat получает animation-back-card, разве не этого хотите? ещё раз проверьте у себя, всё ли корректно?

Comment: В том и дело, что back-card-boat ничего при нажатии не получает. Он же получается не родитель button

Comment: @mr.smile  Странно, вы даже свою вёрстку не знаете? в вашем примере видно же что и как. Придётся на пальцах показывать, вот скрин, думаю уже понятно, что это родители  https://imgur.com/a/D0JJBbh   у меня код нормально работате, оба блока получают класс, вы что то не так делаете.....

Comment: Прошу прощения, мб реально я где туплю, но у меня back-card-boat ничего не добавляется, закинул на codepen, посмотри, пожалуйста, реально не могу понять. https://codepen.io/falkentt/pen/zYxeJJV

Comment: @mr.smile обновил ответ